# I can't retrieve the list of available cookies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, struts2

Once I call the method of following class it returns the list of cookies, but when I try to access the same method from another class it returns `NullPointerException`.

I suppose the reason is `servletRequest` but how to solve it ? is there any other method to implement it ?

```
public class ClientFind extends ActionSupport implements ServletResponseAware,
                                                         ServletRequestAware 
{
    .....
    Cookie coockies[] = servletRequest.getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < coockies.length; i++) {
        if (coockies[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ID")) {
            return coockies[i].getValue();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I have also used the following code but it retunrs `java.lang.NullPointerException` on line 4

```
1        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("Namez", "Tim");
2        cookie.setPath("/");
3        org.apache.http.client.CookieStore cookieStore = null;
4        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
5        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Comment: `coockies.length` sounds dirty :D

Comment: Btw, the question is not clear at all: if you read cookies from the ClientFind action, it works; if you read cookies from another action, it doesn't work ? Can we see the other action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if its what you want but try the following code,

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

public class GetCookiePrintAndSetValue {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "My Browser");

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://localhost:8080/");
    try{
      client.executeMethod(method);
      Cookie[] cookies = client.getState().getCookies();
      for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
        System.err.println(
          "Cookie: " + cookie.getName() +
          ", Value: " + cookie.getValue() +
          ", IsPersistent?: " + cookie.isPersistent() +
          ", Expiry Date: " + cookie.getExpiryDate() +
          ", Comment: " + cookie.getComment());

        cookie.setValue("My own value");
      }
      client.executeMethod(method);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
      method.releaseConnection();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know very little about `ServletResponse`, but if it is the `NullPointerException` that bothers you, you should for example consider the fact that the `getCookies()` method returns `null` if no cookies where sent.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()

**Edit:**
The second exception, which you added after my first response, is easy to catch. You are actually assigning the value `null` to `cookieStore` on line three.

Comment: I am sure two cookies exist.

Comment: I'm sure you do, @TimNorman, but since getCookies() very well might return null, your code should check for it.